# бесконечный UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, tableview

Наверняка уже 100 раз обсуждали, но все же
Куда копать для реализации TableView с заранее неизвестным уровнем вложенности? Navigation, разумеется, должен возвращать на предыдущий уровень.

Comment: Что подразумевается под уровнем вложенности?

Comment: По сути, ориентированный граф, с неизвестным количеством вершин. Данные для TableView беру из JSON, в котором описана иерархия. Если бы я точно знал количество уровней иерархии, то я просто бы сделал n-ное количество TableViewController, но проблема как раз в том, что количество этих уровней иерархии заранее неизвестно (от 2 до n)

Comment: Т.е. при нажатии на ячейку, открывается новый контроллер с новой таблицей?

Comment: Да. и возврат на предыдущий уровень через NavigationBar так же должен быть предусмотрен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете сделать segue для контроллера на самого себя и передавать данные, сколько уровней вложенности не имеет значения. [Исходники примера на GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/ExampleNavigationForDictForSO).

Кратко:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть:

1. Из первого контроллера по нажатию на кнопку "Pass Data" передаем Dictionary с произвольным уровнем вложенности в DataViewController
2. При каждом нажатии "Next level" передаем на 1 уровень глубже
3. Когда достигаем последнего - переходим на DetailsViewController.

Cделайте переход по нажатию на ячейку UITableView и передавайте соответствующие данные.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Все получилось

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте UITableViewController. Сделайте переменную Stack в UITableViewController. Положите в Stack ваш JSON.

При нажатии на ячейку, JSON, начинающийся с элемента, который выбрал пользователь пересылайте в Stack и перезагружайте данные в UITableView. Анимацией имитируйте переход на новый экран (но не делайте переход). При перезагрузке данных UITableView, доставайте из Stack верхний элемент и отображайте его.

Нажатие пользователем "назад" реализуйте программно, выкидывая верхний элемент из Stack и перезагружая данные в UITableView. Если элементы в Stack закончились, отправляйте пользователя на основной экран.