# Как построить структуру для пошагового проходу в tableview

Tags: json, ios, swift, apple

У меня есть JSON:

```
[
{
  "Men": {
    "image": "/url.png",
    "Jeans": [
      {
        "name": "asd",
        "about": "sadvc",
        "image": "/urls.sjd"
      },
      {
        "name": "asd",
        "about": "sadvc",
        "image": "/urls.sjd"
      },
      {
        "name": "asd",
        "about": "sadvc",
        "image": "/urls.sjd"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Women": {
    "image": "/url2.jpeg",
    "All": {}
  }
}
]
```

Как построить struct в коде так, что бы информация "пошагово" показывалась?

Первый ViewController - выбор пола - мужской или женский. В соответствии с выбором, переходило на следующий VC с информацией по выбору типа одежда. В данном случае, к примеру, я выбираю Men. В итоге открывается выбор только Jeans. В третьем VC я уже вижу 3 вида джинс в collection view. У меня получилось только показать вещи по такому JSON -

```
[
{
"about": "qwe",
"image": "/images/Home.png",
"name": "sdv"
},
{
"about": "fs",
"image": "/images/Home.png",
"name": "vcmx"
},
{  "about": "cvb",
"image": "/images/Home.png",
"name": "iums"
}
]
```

Сейчас имеется такая структура

```
struct Clothe: Decodable {
    let about: String
    let name: String
    let image: String
}
```

И функция по загрузке JSON

```
var clothes = [Clothe]()
public func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: "https...bla-bla/ULRhere.json")

    let request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 120.0)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.clothes = try JSONDecoder().decode([Clothe].self, from: data!)
                print(self.clothes)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    completed()

                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON Error")
            }
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Легче всего реализовать это через фильтрацию массива при клике на необходимый пол.

Comment: В чем именно вопрос? Нужен алгоритм или готовый код?)) и будет использоваться один и тот же контроллер или несколько разных?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [бесконечный UITableView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756431/%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-uitableview)

Comment: @VAndrJ Да, это похоже. Но дело в том, что я просто не знаю как построить структру для распознавания JSON файла такого формата. Плюс появляется проблема с развертыванием такого JSON формата на tableView, что бы шаг за шагом переходило. Если у тебя есть желание и возможность помочь мне, то напиши пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

Декодируйте JSON один раз полностью, а затем передавайте в каждый последующий VC одно из полей большого JSON, затем поле вложенного объекта и т.д.